# NULL vs NOT NULL (SQLite)

Tags: sqlite

Is `NULL` in `FooColumn2 TEXT NULL` an explicit way to say nullable? Or does it mean something different?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FooTable (FooColumn1 TEXT NOT NULL, FooColumn2 TEXT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, by default it’s nullable if not explicitly stated as NOT NULL; does not look like NULL is part of the column constraint at all:

[image: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html]
source: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html